# Error while importing file into DB2 from python script

Tags: python, db2, pyodbc

Getting the below error while trying to import a `^` delimited file into a DB2 database using python 2.4.3.

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python25\Usefulscripts\order.py", line 89, in <module>
>     load_order_stack() 
>   File "C:\Python25\Usefulscripts\order.py", line 75, in load_order_stack
>     conn2.execute(importTmp)
> ProgrammingError: ('42601', '[42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "orders_extract"
> ```
>
> was found following "import from ".

Code:

```
import pyodbc

def load_order_stack():
    try:
        conn2 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=db2Database;UID=ueserid;PWD=password')
        importTmp = ("import from orders_extract of del modified by coldel0x5E"
                     "insert_update into test.ORDERS_Table (ORDER_ID,item,price);")
        conn2.execute(importTmp)
        conn2.commit()
```

Comment: Please tell us what did you try, what do you think is the problem. People are much more happy to help when you show them work toward solving it, not just throw work at them :).

Comment: Try putting the filename with full path between single quotes. Does the file exist on the database server?

Comment: Hi Puciek,  yes I did try to load the file in various ways - including quotes withe escape characters, with fully qualified path as well, but got the same error

Comment: Hi Ansgar, no the file does not exist on the database server, actually its on a separate app server where i have my python script running. Would this be an issue ?

Answer (score 2):

IMPORT is not an SQL statement. It is a DB2 Command Line Processor (CLP) command and as such can only be run by the said CLP.

There is an SQL interface to some CLP commands via calls to the ADMIN_CMD() stored procedure, please check the manual: [IMPORT using ADMIN_CMD](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html)

Comment: I was able to get rid of the original error by using the "ADMIN_CMD" command as below. However, getting a different error now ->      "Error: (' ', '[ ] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL3030C An I/O error (reason = "sqlofopn -2029060079") occurred while opening the input file.\r\n (-3030) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

Comment: Clearly DB2 cannot open the file. I hope you realize that the file you import from must reside on the database server and should be readable by the instance owner user.

Comment: Is there an alternate way whereby i can import a file which exists on my app server (where the python script resides) different from the db server ? I don't have access to the database server file system

Comment: You could execute the DB2 CLP and pass the IMPORT command to it, making sure the DB2 environment is properly initialized. I think one way to do it is write the CONNECT and IMPORT commands to a file, then call `db2cmd.exe -c db2 -f yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of reading the file, line by line, and inserting into your database. This will definitely be slower than any native import operation. Assuming your delimited file structure is, and the file is named `input.txt`:

```
ORDER_ID^item^price
1^'bat'^50.00
2^'ball'^25.00
```

Code:

```
import csv
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=db2Database;UID=ueserid;PWD=password')
cursor = connection.cursor()

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter='^')
    # get column names from header in first line
    columns = ','.join(next(rows))
    for row in rows:
        # build sql with placeholders for insert
        placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(row))
        sql = 'insert into ({}) values ({});'.format(columns, placeholders)

        # execute parameterized database insert
        cursor.execute(sql, row)
        cursor.commit()
```

Play around with `commit()` placement, you probably want to commit in batches to improve performance.

Comment: I tried this solution and i got an error saying "iSeries Access ODBC Driver SQL7008 INCLU00001 not valid for operation. (-7008) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

I fixed by creating a journal to the table i am inserting records into and it solved the problem.

Thanks