# DB2 cannot find load in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I cannot use the load cmd inside a stored procedure, got this error

```
declare cursor_x cursor for select cod, name, hired project from emp.table_1;
load from cursor_x of cursor insert into emp.table_2 nonrecoverable
```

Without *load* it is working fine.

```
{0:0} An unexpected token "from" was found following "emp.table_1
   load".  Expected tokens may include:  "WHERE".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.1301
```

Without *load* it is working fine.

Comment: LOAD is not an SQL statement. It's a command which can be executed by Db2 Command Line Processor. The relational way to use LOAD as SQL statement is described at the [LOAD command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-load-using-admin-cmd) link. You can combine a cursor declaration and its use in LOAD with a single `LOAD FROM (query-statement)` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while importing file into DB2 from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562381/error-while-importing-file-into-db2-from-python-script)

Comment: Yeah, what I want to do is to call a stored procedure, which makes some prechecks like objects are existing are not. When the checks are valid than I want to call admin cmd for loading and copying data. My question will be, when I define a temp table in the stored procedure, can I use it in the load.
`load from c1 of cursor replace into temp1`
Will the load find the temp1 table?

Comment: If you mean Declared or Created Global Temporary Table by "temp table" then no, you can't use [D|C]GTTs with [LOAD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-load): **INTO table-name** 
    Specifies the database table into which the data is to be loaded. **This table cannot be a system table, a declared temporary table, or a created temporary table.**

Comment: Ok just understand, is it possible to call admin cmds from stored procedure and can I verify if the admin commands are run successful?

Comment: Sure, Db2 allows you to call one SP from another one of course. [Calling procedures from triggers or SQL routines](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=procedures-calling-from-triggers-sql-routines).

Comment: And how to verify such a result of the command execution?

Comment: By presence of loaded rows in the target table. Or analyzing the result set returned. See the `Result set information` description at the 1-st link.

Comment: `CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(
'set integrity for emp.table_2 immediate checked'
);`
Do I miss anything, got this error

_[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "integrity" was found following "SET".  Expected tokens may include:  "TAPE".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11_